# React Native. Animated.subtract

Tags: react-native

Don't know why, but `Animated` doesn't have a property `subtract` (eg. `Animated.subtract(a,b)`.
How can I subtract two `Animated.Values`?

Comment: What's the use case for this? Perhaps this could be accomplished by interpolating the interpolated value somehow.

Comment: Yes, I used this technique, that worked.

Comment: @Edgar could you elaborate further on how to achieve this using interpolation?

Comment: @Edgar nevermind

Comment: `Animated.subtract` is available since React Native 0.56 (available since April 2018). However Expo for example is still running on React Native 0.55.4 so you won't find it there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way to do this is to combine `Animated.add` with `Animated.multiply` i.e. `Animated.add(x, Animated.multiply(-1, y))`

Answer (score 5):

Animated has now a subtract method.

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#subtract

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by `Interpolating` the interpolated value.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/animated.html#interpolation

Answer (score 1):

For those who is looking for it, just use

```
Animated.add(endAnimatedValue, startAnimatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
}))
```

This part:

```
inputRange: [0, 1],
outputRange: [1, 0],
```

negate the outcome of  the 'startAnimatedValue'

Answer (score 1):

There is no Animated.subtract but there is Animated.add which you can also use for subtracting. In the end subtracting is adding negative values.

```
const y = new Animated.Value(4)
const x = new Animated.Value(-2)

Animated.add(y, x) // Results in animated value 2
```

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/animated.html#add

Comment: This only solves the problem if you're initializing the value. You can't use this solution if, for example, `x = new Animated.value(2)`, unless you use `setValue` first, but then that kind of defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Full example**

```js
import { Animated } from 'react-native'

const a = new Animated.Value(2);
const b = new Animated.Value(1)
const val = Animated.subtract(a,b) //val = b - a;
```